# Inline responsive menu with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive header in my app with the following elements:

- a logo (`<img>`)
- a search bar (`<input>`)
- a link (`<a>`)
- two boxes (`<div>`)

---

Elements position depends of the screen size:

### Medium screens (`md-*`)

[image]

---

### Small screens (`sm-*`)

[image]

---

### Extra small screens (`xs-*`)

[image]

---

I manage to create each of these layouts, but not with the responsive classes of Bootstrap... Can you help me here?

Here is the simple code I used to make this example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row vertical-aligned">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img class="logo" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cocacola_PNG14.png"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Search bar -->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="input-group search-width">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <a>Launch advanced research...</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav boxes -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="nav-button">Profil</div>
      <div class="nav-button">Settings</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/sf46neL9/87/)

Comment: Maybe use FlexBox?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue, i found 2 problems.

The first one with your md screen, the input field and the paragraph would not stay inline, because of the float property, this would be solved by editing the css of the .input-group class as float left. The second problem for the small screen, is that the div will not stack over one other with a 100% width because you set the css property display: flex and center, I created a media query for the window size of small (<768px) to display those div as inline-block. Please comment for any additional help or problems, the code below should be working fine.

UPDATE - Solving the additional requirements for the md and sm size:

For the first problem i added padding top to the id=link, in a media query that will target only md devices, for the second problem with media queries i edited the position of those divs with position relative and left/top attributes.

Thanks
Fabrizio Bertoglio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row vertical-aligned">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <img class="logo" src="http://pngimg.com/upload/cocacola_PNG14.png"/>
    </div>
    <!-- Search bar -->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"> 
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="link">
                <a>Launch advanced research...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav buttons -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="boxes">
      <div class="nav-button">Profil</div>
      <div class="nav-button">Settings</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code

```
    </body>
</html>


.vertical-aligned {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.nav-button {
  height: 70px;
  width: 80px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-group {
    float: left !important;
}


@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    #link {
        padding-top: 6px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
    .vertical-aligned {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #boxes {
        max-width: 300px;
        position: relative;
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-179px);
        top: -5%;
    }

    a {
        position: relative;
        top: 49px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fabrizio, but it seems in `md-*` screen `<input>` and `<a>` are not inline... Furthermore, in `sm-*` screen, the boxes are **under** the `<a>`

Comment: thanks. For the first issue, a very easy fix would be applying padding-top of 6px to the <div class="col-md-4"> of the a tag. It should look ok until the screen is 1184px and the p tag ends up being two rows, but maybe you are looking at a better option for solving the problem?
while I am searching for another quick solution for the second problem.

Comment: @Mistalis Hello, I found a solution for both issues. I can not find any better solution without having additional information. I edited my post with the new code. To solve the second problem I used position absolute with the two divs and top/left attributes within a media query.

Comment: I think the first answer you posted was better (more simple, more efficient) as the second one include too much fixed values (sizes in px). Furthermore, it is broken on IE

Comment: @Mistalis I had also today some problems with my flex-box, I solved it by using justify-content: center. I was using a flex-box with flex-direction:column, while you are using it with flex-direction: rows. So basically with flex-direction:column; you use align-center to horizontally align items centrally, while with justify content: center you do something similar to vertically align them centrally, but using justify and the effect is very similar. With row is the opposite logic. You need to find your best solution.

Comment: I think there is still a clearer way to achieve this, so I don't *accept* the answer. Anyway, I upvoted your effort because it helps me. TY :-)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this answer can help you.
You can use @media to manage every element size in different layout, 
for example, on laptop layout:

```
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) { 

//your css here
}

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */
@media screen 
  and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
//your css code here
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t526Lt_O7zo